# Output HTML using a template and JSON for data

Tags: python, json, amp-html

What's a good way for me to output (AMP compliant) HTML using a template and JSON for the data? I have a nice little python script:

```
import requests
import json
from bs4 import BeautifulSoup

url = requests.get('https://www.perfectimprints.com/custom-promos/20492/Beach-Balls.html')
source = BeautifulSoup(url.text, 'html.parser')

products = source.find_all('div', class_="product_wrapper")
infos = source.find_all('div', class_="categories_wrapper")

def get_category_information(category):
  category_name = category.find('h1', class_="category_head_name").text
  return {
    "category_name": category_name.strip()
  }

category_information = [get_category_information(info) for info in infos]

with open("category_info.json", "w") as write_file:
  json.dump(category_information, write_file)

def get_product_details(product):
  product_name = product.find('div', class_="product_name").a.text
  sku = product.find('div', class_="product_sku").text
  product_link = product.find('div', class_="product_image_wrapper").find("a")["href"]
  src = product.find('div', class_="product_image_wrapper").find('a').find("img")["src"]
  return {
      "title": product_name,
      "link": product_link.strip(),
      "sku": sku.strip(),
      "src": src.strip()
  }

all_products = [get_product_details(product) for product in products]

with open("products.json", "w") as write_file:
  json.dump({'items': all_products}, write_file)

print("Success")
```

Which generates the JSON files I need. However, I now need to use those JSON files and input it into my template ([gist](https://gist.github.com/Mortiferr/bf3ac6a102f133135e93a8a0e2608c63)) everywhere it says `{{ JSON DATA HERE }}`.

I'm not even sure where to start. I'm most comfortable with JavaScript so I'd like to use that if possible. I figure something involving Node.js.

Comment: Use a templating engine, `jinja` come to mind http://jinja.pocoo.org/

Comment: @RockyLi I can't have any templating syntax in my HTML due to [AMP](https://www.ampproject.org/).

Comment: I admit I don't know what `AMP` is, but you can import `jinja` like any other module and store your template as strings.

Comment: @RockyLi It's basically normal HTML / CSS pages but with extreme restrictions in the name of speed.

Comment: So you're using python to generate those pages right? If python works I don't understand why Jinja can't. You `import jinja` like you `import requests`

Comment: You need a mapping of what values go in which `{{ JSON HERE }}` slot. It's not difficult, just a bit tedious. You might find some patterns emerging to help with repetition. Hard to help further without seeing the data and the template. Have a go and post when you get stuck or need help refactoring.

Comment: @RobG I have that (`{{ productname }}`, just not in the gist), for example. Can expand your explanation a bit? I'm not sure I understand what you mean 100% by "You need a mapping of what values go in which {{ JSON HERE }} slot." Thanks!

Comment: @RockyLi Because information has to go in the HTML file itself (`<title>{% block title %}{% endblock %}</title>` for example) and AMP would complain about that. I have to generate clean HTML before AMP ever sees it. I suppose I could generate the file *then* send to AMP...I'll give that shot.

Comment: Presumably there's value somewhere in your data that fits into `<link rel="canonical" href="{{ JSON DATA HERE }}">`, so you need to identify it in the data structure then put it into the *href* value. It seems [*amp-mustache-0.2.js*](https://ampbyexample.com/components/amp-mustache/) is being loaded, it may help with templating.

Comment: @RobG the problem is that the source of {{src}} is using `<amp-list>` templating so I would have to write something to input things into the href like that, as AMP doesn't allow it except for within the almighty `amp-list` custom html element.

Comment: @Patrick—sorry, I know nothing of [*amp-mustache*](https://www.ampproject.org/docs/reference/components/amp-mustache), all I can do is learn it, which I don't have time for right now, RL intervenes…

Comment: @RobG Well thank you for the insights either way

Comment: Of course you can `html = template.render(your_dict)` and then return that `html`. A templating engine just means it takes in a templates and returns HTML, it doesn't need it's own implementation to read or even know what HTML is.

Answer (score 4, accepted):

Here's how you can render HTML with a template engine by itself and use it to return pure HTML:

```
from jinja2 import Template

me = Template('<h1>Hello {{x}}<h1>')
html = me.render({'x': 'world'})
return html
```

`html` is your rendered HTML string. Alternatively, you can render from a file:

```
from jinja2 import Template
with open('your_template.html') as file_:
    template = Template(file_.read())
html = template.render(your_dict)
return html
```

Since you're going to generate HTML one way or another, using a template engine will save you much time. You can also do {% for item in list %} and such thing will greatly simplify your task.

Comment: So the OP needs to replace `{{ JSON DATA HERE }}` with `{{myPropertyRef}}` where *myPropertyRef* maps to a value in the data object like `{..., "myPropertyRef": value, ...}`.

Comment: @RobG yep, and it fits nicely with json since it's pretty much a dictionary file.

Comment: @RobG @Rocky Li okay this worked for the most part. I'm just not 100% sure what should be in the `my_dict` variable?

Comment: Assuming you want `{{ variable_name }}` in template, you'll need to structure your dict like `{ 'variable_name': value, ..}` in the dict you pass in.

Comment: Okay last question I promise. I'm getting `html = template.render(cat_dict).stream(name='file_').dump('index.html')
AttributeError: 'str' object has no attribute 'stream'` as an error message. Here's my code: https://hastebin.com/aretigirar.py. Any ideas why?

Comment: You are streaming a HTML string, which is just like any other string. What are you trying to accomplish here? Save to a file? Upload? I don’t understand

Comment: @Patrick—don't put additional information in comments, add it to the original post.

Comment: I'm trying to save a file @RockyLi with the rendered html

Comment: `with(open('newfile.html','w') as f: f.write(html)`?