# json2html: how to display an image URL as an image

Tags: python, json, flask

Actually, I have 2 questions for this. I have a json like this

```
[
    {
        "id": 601,
        "imdb_id": "tt0068646",
        "imdb_rating": "9.2",
        "language": "English, Italian, Latin",
        "poster": "https://m.media-amazon.com/images/M/MV5BM2MyNjYxNmUtYTAwNi00MTYxLWJmNWYtYzZlODY3ZTk3OTFlXkEyXkFqcGdeQXVyNzkwMjQ5NzM@._V1_SX300.jpg",
        "title": "The Godfather",
        "year": 1972
    },
    {
        "id": 603,
        "imdb_id": "tt0071562",
        "imdb_rating": "9.0",
        "language": "English, Italian, Spanish, Latin, Sicilian",
        "poster": "https://m.media-amazon.com/images/M/MV5BMWMwMGQzZTItY2JlNC00OWZiLWIyMDctNDk2ZDQ2YjRjMWQ0XkEyXkFqcGdeQXVyNzkwMjQ5NzM@._V1_SX300.jpg",
        "title": "The Godfather Part II",
        "year": 1974
    },
    {
        "id": 622,
        "imdb_id": "tt0108052",
        "imdb_rating": "9.0",
        "language": "English, Hebrew, German, Polish, Latin",
        "poster": "https://m.media-amazon.com/images/M/MV5BNDE4OTMxMTctNmRhYy00NWE2LTg3YzItYTk3M2UwOTU5Njg4XkEyXkFqcGdeQXVyNjU0OTQ0OTY@._V1_SX300.jpg",
        "title": "Schindler's List",
        "year": 1993
    }
]
```

After do a json2html and return like this

```
    movies_data = get_recommended_movies().json
    for movie_data in movies_data:
        imdb_id = movie_data["imdb_id"]
        movie_data["imdb_id"] = "https://www.imdb.com/title/" + imdb_id

    #movies_data = json.dumps(get_recommended_movies().json)
    html_data = json2html.convert(json=movies_data)
    return html_data
```

The webpage is rendered with a table. My question is that how to render the poster url as an image in the table and. How to display it as a clickable URL in the table

Comment: i don't see that functionality in the json2html python plugin. You need some kind of template (or just generate the table trivially). See https://stackoverflow.com/questions/52958246/output-html-using-a-template-and-json-for-data

Comment: thanks. I will looking to a some kind of template now

Answer (score 0):

It's not possible with that library, cannot supports html templates, only transform json to a html table

You can try to add some javascript, but my recommendation is use other library, the latest version it's too old (Jul 3, 2019)

check https://handlebarsjs.com/